# Divide by a number only non Nan values in a data frame column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Lets say i have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
       Col1
0    100,000,000
1    234,343,000
2      NaN
3    213,564,545
4      NaN
5    678,000
6     200
```

how can divide the non NaN values in Col1 with 1000 and have this desirable output:

```
        Col1            Col2
0    100,000,000      100,000
1    234,343,000      234,343
2        NaN            NaN
3    213,564,545      213,564
4        NaN            NaN
5      678,000          678
6     200               0.2
```

I tried to do `df['Col1'].div(1000)` but it is not working because of the NaN values

Comment: Do you have integers or strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have strings, so dividing by 1000 is just removing the last comma and last 3 digits. You can use a regex:

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].str.replace(',?\d{,3}$', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
          Col1     Col2
0  100,000,000  100,000
1  234,343,000  234,343
2          NaN      NaN
3  213,564,545  213,564
4          NaN      NaN
5      678,000      678
```

##### emulating a true division:

###### only small numbers as float

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].str.replace(r'(.*?)(,?(\d{1,3}))$',
                                    lambda m: m.group(1) if m.group(1) else ('0.'+m.group(3).zfill(3)),
                                    regex=True)
```

output:

```
          Col1     Col2
0  100,000,000  100,000
1  234,343,000  234,343
2          NaN      NaN
3  213,564,545  213,564
4          NaN      NaN
5      678,000      678
6           23    0.023
```

###### all floats

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].str.replace(r'(.*?)(,?(\d{1,3}))$',
                                    lambda m: (m.group(1) if m.group(1) else '0')+'.'+m.group(3).zfill(3),
                                    regex=True)
```

output:

```
          Col1         Col2
0  100,000,000  100,000.000
1  234,343,000  234,343.000
2          NaN          NaN
3  213,564,545  213,564.545
4          NaN          NaN
5      678,000      678.000
6           23        0.023
```

Comment: Hey @mozway, yes they are string and i tried you solution for my example as it is working good. But what if the number (string) is like "200" and what i want to get in the output is 0.2. With your solution it will remove that string from the row. How can this be solved

Comment: Edited my question ,added row with index 6. Can you please check?

Comment: @user14073111 is it on purpose that `213,564,545` does not become `213,564.545`?

Comment: Yes 213,564,545 should be 213,564.545, so thats why i was concern if we just remove the last 3 digits

Comment: @user14073111 I provided all possibilities, so now you can chose ;)